# Class Designing in C# - DAL

Tags: c#, class

I came across a Data Access Layer Class that was made up entirely of static methods. This class was consumed by a Web Application

For e.g

```
public class DataAccessLayer
{
Public static PersonDetails GetDetails(int iPersonID);
{
//implementation
}
Public static bool SaveDetails(PersonDetails objPerson);
{
//implementation
}

}
```

Is it a good practice to write such code. I can understand the fact that the performance will be slightly better when I use static methods, but will this cause any concurrency errors when multiple users call the Page?

Comment: Whether this is a good practice depends on your coding standards. If objects are not read+write between the methods (as @Paddy pointed out) this code is essentially fine - especially in the case where they wrap stored procedures (this is called a static adapter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to write such code.

Firing offense in my teams, breaks so many good practices I suggest whoever writes something like that goes to my competitors and works for them.

> I can understand the fact that the performance will be slightly better when I use static methods.

Like 0.000000000000000000001%?

> but will this cause any concurrency errors when multiple users call the Page?

Depends how the methods are written. It violates object orientation, though, makes dependency injection harder, makes it hard to use proper transactional demarcations under a transaction coordinator and makes it hard to unit test / mock things.

Answer (score 2):

Static or not, you may get concurrency issues, it depends very much on how the actual code in your data access methods is written (e.g. use of transactions, are there fields used for concurrency checking in your data source etc.).

Comment: The code in this case is relatively simple, and i do not see many concurrent users. But was wondering if using static methods to implement cases such as these was a good Object oriented Practice?

Answer (score 0):

The static variable dies in a standalone application, because the
garbage collector cleans all your object because your application has
ended.

But if you are using this in a webapplication, your application is not
dead until your web server dies. So even if you closes the web browser,
your web server is not close. Try to shut down your server and your
variable will be no more.